# How to switch users without sleep?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, multi-user

I have a new 2013 Nexus tablet running Android 4.4.2. I like that it supports multiple user profiles, but the only way I have found to switch profiles is to put the tablet to sleep by pushing the power button or closing the case.

Surely there is a more direct way to reach the login screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a Nexus 7 V2 and when you bring down the notification area there is a buton with you username on it and the picture you chose. When you click that button, it will bring you to the log in screen where you can switch users. Doing it this way does not end your session.